# Phonegap noob qestion about media

Tags: cordova

So I'm following the tutorial on the cordova website for using the [media class in phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media). I copied the full example code for `media.getCurrentPosition`  From the looks of it shouldnt the audio start immediately since playAudio(src) is called in the onDeviceReady() function?  Or am I misunderstading how DeviceReady works?

Answer (score 0):

`onDeviceReady` is fired when the Phonegap API is ready. So the media is played. Infact you need to call any phonegap function only from inside this function.

[Phonegap events](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready)